# changing width of face book like box

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I integrated Facebook like box on my page. I like to change the width of the box. How can I do this!

my config

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 85px; height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://optisolbusiness.com/gonzobidz/&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21"></iframe>
```

switch width this [image] to like this [image: enter code here]

Comment: So you're trying to display the Like count without the button?

Comment: @jhiro009: No i just want extent width of the count box like second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the width of the counter. Review the [Like Button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/): you can only set the width of the container that holds the button and the counter.